# Label x-axis nearest to thousand in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use scale_x_continuous and round my labels to nearest thousand. For example if my X axis are 1234567,2345566.... I want it to be 1235,2346.I have used sequencing to split my x-axis in deciles. When I am rounding it to thousands and then dividing by 1000 I will show it by example. Its making 1235000 and after dividing its becoming 1235 which I want but since sclae_x_continuous observes that all the numbers till 3million(which is now 3k) comes in the first decile its printing all the labels at the same place. The code I am using is:

```
ggplot(
  data = cummulative, 
  aes(
    x = seq(1,length(cummulative$Frequency)),
    y = Cum.Percent.,
    group = 1
  )
) + 
geom_line(colour="red", size=1) + 
theme_classic() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, hjust = 1, size=8)) + 
labs(x="Number of Customer (in thousands)",y="Product Share (%)") +
ggtitle("Pareto Chart") +ylim(0,100.1) +
(scale_x_continuous(
  breaks = seq(
    0, 
    length(cummulative$Frequency), 
    length(cummulative$Frequency)/10
  )
))
```

Please also find the image here:[image]

Thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: try this? `scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(seq( 0,  length(cummulative$Frequency), length(cummulative$Frequency)/10 )`

Comment: @AdamQuek Its just giving me to nearest 0.1millions. Its moving the decile and dividing it into 5 or 6 parts according to the suitability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `ggplot` handle the breaks instead of specifying them manually. You'll get a nice interval. Dividing X a priori by 1000 will get you very close to the solution.

Provide a reproducible example if you want a better solution.

```
ggplot(
  data = cummulative, 
  aes(
    x = seq_along(Frequency) / 1000,
    y = Cum.Percent.
  )
) + 
geom_line(colour="red", size=1) + 
theme_classic() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, hjust = 1, size=8)) + 
labs(
  x = "Number of Customer (in thousands)",
  y = "Product Share (%)"
) +
ggtitle("Pareto Chart") +
ylim(0, 100.1) +
scale_x_continuous()
```

Comment: dont mind me asking but i am new to R and to coding as well. Why have you changed the x axis. Do you mean to say that divide all the points of x by thousand so that the graph itself will diminish? If yes, you have changed x from seq(1,length(cummulative$Frequency) to seq_along(Frequency) / 1000. What is the reason

Comment: I think what I understand is you are giving x/1000 value to the x axis and along the way it will produce at a difference of decile. But how to know if it will plot 10 points or more or less??

Comment: I just ran its plotting at 1000 2000 and 3000 thats it